# Qt this->update() is not entirely updating the widget

Tags: qt, events

I created a simple widget with a button, a slot for the button, a resize event and a paint event.
I expect when I click on the button it draws an ellipse at a random position and the button disappears.

But I get: the ellipse is drawn and the button is not hidden after `this->update`.
Even stranger, when I uncomment the `button->hide();` every time I click it draws a new eclipse but the old ellipses are still there. Something is wrong with updating and the paint event.

If I resize the window by dragging with the mouse the update of the paint event works as expected. Only the last ellipse stays and the button is hidden.

My Qt version is Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_32_bit

Here is the code of the widget:

```
PATrackSetter::PATrackSetter(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent){
    button = new PAButton(this);
    connect(button,SIGNAL(clicked(int, QString, QString)),this,SLOT(on_TileClicked(int, QString, QString)));
    button->setFixedSize(100, 100);
    button->move(0,0);
    button->show();
}

void PATrackSetter::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *){

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    QPen pen = QPen();
    pen.setColor(Qt::yellow);
    painter.setPen(pen);
    painter.drawEllipse(100,rand() % 500 +10,5,5);
}

void PATrackSetter::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *)
{

}

void PATrackSetter::on_TileClicked(int buttonID, QString buttonText, QString newButtonStatus){

   button->hide();
   this->update();

}
```

Can anyone see what I did wrong?

Edit:

I added more code to the project and I run into the same issue. I added the following lines into the MainWindow class and the updating inside the PATrackSetter widget doesn't work anymore as expected. I really dont understand why. But if I uncomment these lines it works again well.

```
QPalette paletteBGColor;
QBrush brush;
brush.setColor(Qt::black);
paletteBGColor.setBrush(QPalette::Background, brush);
this->setPalette(paletteBGColor);
```

Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

If the button is not hidden then slot is not called. I guess you didn't put `void on_TileClicked(int, QString, QString)` in `slots:` section in header file, or signal/slot signatures don't match (in which case there must be warning in debug output in runtime).

Comment: The slot worked well because a new circle was drawn on every click (triggered by this slot). Mystery was that the old circles remained on screen and the button was not hidden; at least not before resizing the window. After hours of error searching I gave up. There is no error. It was not to much code and I decided to create the application from scratch. And it works as expected. I'm using these methods in a lot of projects and never had this issue. I have no clue what and when it went wrong. Sorry for bothering and thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

When you are reimplementing `paintEvent` you should expect that every update on the `QWidget`, even manually or by the parent window, will call the `paintEvent` once. So, it's up to you to handle cleaning the previous state or draw on the previous drawings. The behavior you explained is quite normal.
It ***seems*** that you are not calling `setGeometry` on the `PATrackSetter` when you are instantiating it. So, in the update hierarchy, its size is not known and you should expect partial redraws and undefined behaviors.